# OpenGL not rendering as expected

Tags: java, android, opengl-es

If I have the screen setup with the following

```
    gl.glViewport(0,0,width,height);  //Reset the current viewport
    gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_PROJECTION); //select the projection matrix
    gl.glLoadIdentity();            //Reset the Projection Matrix

    gl.glOrthof(0f,1f,0f,1f,-1f,1f);
```

and the vertices set up as follows

```
this._vertices=new float[]{
                0.0f,0.5f,0.0f,   //V1 bottom left
                0.0f,1.0f,0.0f,    //V2 top left
                0.5f,0.5f,0.0f,  //V3 Bottom right
                0.5f,1.0f,0.0f   //V4 top right
        };
```

then when drawing I do

```
gl.glTranslatef(0.0f,0.0f,0.0f);
```

it places the square in the top left (i thought 0,0 was bottom left?)

and then

```
gl.glTranslatef(0.5f,-0.5f,0.0f);
```

places the square in the middle of the screen (suggesting the bottom is actually -1.0f rather than 0.0f)

How do I make the bottom left of my screen start from 0,0?

Update------

I have found that if I change the line

```
gl.glOrthof(0f,1f,0f,1f,-1f,1f);
```

to

```
gl.glOrthof(0f,1f,1f,0f,-1f,1f);
```

then nothing changes (ie the top left is still 0,0 and bottom left is 0,-1)

however if I leave the line out completely then the origin is in the centre of the screen (ie top left is -1,-1)

Comment: I think that in the computer graphics world (0, 0) is typically the top left, not the bottom left as you might have learned in math. Don't know if this is something you can change.

Comment: I have been led to believe that OpenGL places 0,0 at the bottom right unlike you would normally expect for computers. The above code seems to confirm this, however my screen seems to be in the negative portion of the y axis.....

Comment: I suppose that is the case after some googling. My mistake.

Comment: `glTranslatef (0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f)` is literally completely useless. You are translating 0 units in every direction.

Comment: but does glTranslatef (0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f) not simply place the top left of my quad at co-ordinates 0,0? Or am I not understanding it properly? If I change the line to glTranslatef (0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f) then it draws it in the centre of the screen.

Comment: `glTranslatef (0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f)` actually does nothing. A translation matrix that translates coordinates **0.0** units in every direction boils down to an identity matrix. When you multiply something by an identity matrix, nothing changes. So if you use `glTranslatef (0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f)` your quad starts at Y = **0.5** and finishes at Y = **1.0**. You would need to translate it (**0.0**, **-0.5**, **0.0**) for your quad to start at the bottom-left corner.

Comment: ok, but the issue is that I would expect the line glTranslatef (0.5f, 0.5f, 0.0f) to draw in the centre of the screen but I need to use glTranslatef (0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f). I thought I had made the bottom left of my screen 0,0 rather than 0,-1?

Comment: `glTranslatef (0.5f, 0.5f, 0.0f)` would actually push your quad off the screen completely. The viewport is mapped to (0,0) - (1,1) given your projection matrix. Your quad would start at Y = **1.0** and finish at Y = **1.5**.

Comment: Ah, So translate effectively moves my quad by the translate values rather than placing my quad at the translate values?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. Technically it *multiplies the current matrix* by a translation matrix (and this is why I mentioned `glTranslatef (0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f)` degenerating into an identity matrix earlier), but that is the end result.

Comment: Great thanks, that now makes total sense. The fact that I had this working appears to have been luck rather than design......

Comment: @user3580294: Never make assumptions. By default OpenGL places its coordinate system origin in the lower left with positive x going right and positive y going up. And it's perfectly possible to flip this by flipping the sign of one of the projection matrix axes.

Answer (score 0):

The `glOrthof` is used to create your screen coordinate system, since its input parameters are left, right, top and bottom I can not understand where the confusion lies. If you wish your top left corner is the (0,0) point then just set the top and left parameters to zero and bottom and right to some positive values so that positive X is to the right and positive Y is downwards.

Some very common cases of usage of `glOrthof` are:

- View coordinate system where you insert `(0,0)` as top-left and `(screenHeight , screenWidth)` as bottom-right. In quite a few cases the bottom-left is at `(0,0)` though.
- Graph like coordinate system where screen centre is at `(0,0)` and then top-left is at `(1,-1)` and bottom-right at `(-1,1)`
- Normalized view system which has the screen centre at `(0,0)` but height is relative to width depending on the screen ratio. So top-left is at `(-1,-(screenHeight/screenWidth))` and bottom-right at `(1, screenHeight/screenWidth)`.

You should note that only in 1st and 3rd cases your square will always be drawn as a square and not as a rectangle (where `a/b = screenWidth/screenHeight`). So choose which suits your application best.

You should know that `glOrthof` is also very useful for panning and zooming. Instead of doing some strange translations and scales you can simply change `glOrthof` parameters so that you display a certain part of your scene.